# Почему getClass и overload дают разные ответы?

Tags: java

Почему getClass и overload дают разные ответы?
Пример кода

```
public class Sint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Object ob=(Object)"строка";
        System.out.println(ob.getClass()==Object.class); //False
        System.out.println(ob.getClass()==String.class); //True
        System.out.println("");
        f(ob);
    }
    static void f(Object i){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
 static void f(String i){
        System.out.println("String");
    }
}
```

В консоль выводится

```
false
true

Object
```

т.е при вызове метода getClass() переменная ob -это String(хоте привел её к Object     Object ob=(Object)"строка")
а при overload -вызывается метод по Object

Comment: Наверное потому, решение какой метод вызывать принимается во время компиляции? Компилятор видит, что переменная заявлена как Object. значит надо генерировать код, вызывающий метод для Object. Странно что для вопросов на stackoveflow интернет есть, а для руководств по языкам программирования его сразу нет.

Comment: @Sergey вопрос то был ещё про `getClass()`, а вы сразу человека высмеиваете.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что перегрузка работает при компиляции и выводит объявленный тип переменной, а `getClass()` работает в рантайме и выдаёт реальный тип объекта.